# scipy optimize minimize not finding optimal solution

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimize

I have a constrained optimization problem where I have a number of
products I want to spend money on and estimate my total returns based on models
I built for each individual product.

I'm using scipy.optimzie.minimize to find the optimal spend given the
individual models output. The problem I'm having is that the optimizer
finishes with a "optimizer terminated successfully" flag, but very clearly
does not find the optimal solution. In fact, the output using the original
seed/x0 is better than the output produced from the optimizer. I put a print
statement in the objective function and you can see at one point it just drops off
a cliff. Does anyone have any idea why this would happen/how to fix it?

I've included a reduced version of my code below.

If my products are ['P1','P2',... 'P9'], and I have a model for each of them

```
 # estimates returns on spend for each product
  model1 = lambda money : func1(money *betas_a)
  model2 = lambda money : func2(money,*betas_b)
  ... etc
```

where func is one of

```
def power_curve(x,beta1,beta2):
    return beta1*x**beta2

def mm_curve(x,beta1,beta2):
    "Beta2 >= 0"
    return (beta1*x)/(1+beta2*x)

def dbl_exponential(x,beta1,beta2,beta3,beta4):
    return beta1**(beta2**(x/beta4))*beta3

def neg_exp(x,beta1,beta2):
    "Beta2 > 0"
    return beta1*(1-np.exp(-beta2*x))
```

I now want to optimize my spend in each in order to maximize my total returns.
To do this is use `scipy.optimize.minimize` with a wrapper around the following function:

```
def budget(products, budget, betas, models):
  """
  Given a budget distributed across each product, estimate total returns.

  products = str: names of each individual product
  budget = list-floats: amount of money/spend corresponding to each product
  models = list-funcs: function to use to predict individual returns corresponding to each product
  betas = dict: keys are product names - values are list of betas to feed to corresponding model
  """

  results = []
  target_total = 0 # total returns

  assert len(products) == len(budget) == len(betas)

  # for each product, calculate return using corresponding model
  for v,b,m in zip(products,budget,models):
      tpred = m(b,*betas[v])
      target_total+=tpred
      results.append({'val':v,'budget':b, 'tpred':tpred})
  # if you watch this you can see it drops off dramatically towards the end
  print(target_total)
  return results, target_total
```

Minimum Reproducible Code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

### Setup inputs to the optimizer

vals = ['P1','P2','P3','P4','P5','P6','P7','P8','P9']

funcs = [dbl_exponential,
      mm_curve,
      power_curve,
      mm_curve,
      neg_exp,
      power_curve,
      power_curve,
      mm_curve,
      dbl_exponential]

betas = {'P1': [0.018631215601097723,0.6881958654622713,43.84956270498627,
            1002.1010110475437],
      'P2': [0.002871159199956573, 1.1388317502737174e-06],
      'P3': [0.06863672099961649, 0.7295132426289046],
      'P4': [0.009954885796211378, 3.857169894090025e-05],
      'P5': [307.624705578708, 1.4454030580404746e-05],
      'P6': [0.0875910297422766, 0.6848303282418671],
      'P7': [0.12147343508583974, 0.6573539731442877],
      'P8': [0.002789390181221983, 5.72554293489956e-07],
      'P9': [0.02826834133593836,0.8999750236756555,1494.677373273538,
            6529.1531372261725]
}

bounds = [(4953.474502264151, 14860.423506792453),
       (48189.39647820754, 144568.18943462262),
       (10243.922611886792, 30731.767835660376),
       (6904.288592358491, 20712.865777075473),
       (23440.199762641503, 70320.5992879245),
       (44043.909679905664, 132131.729039717),
       (9428.298255754717, 28284.89476726415),
       (53644.56626556605, 160933.69879669815),
       (8205.906018773589, 24617.718056320766)]

seed = [9906.949005,
     96378.792956,
     20487.845224,
     13808.577185,
     46880.399525,
     88087.81936,
     18856.596512,
     107289.132531,
     16411.812038]

wrapper = lambda b: -budget(vals,b,betas, funcs)[1] # negative to get *maximum* output

## Optimizer Settings
tol = 1e-16
maxiter = 10000
max_budget = 400000
# total spend can't exceed max budget
constraint = [{'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda budget: max_budget-sum(budget)}]

# The output from the seed is better than the final "optimized" output
print('DEFAULT OUTPUT TOTAL:', wrapper(seed))

res = optimize.minimize(wrapper, seed, bounds = bounds,
                tol = tol, constraints = (constraint),
                options={'maxiter':maxiter})

print("Optimizer Func Output:", res.fun)
```

Comment: What do you mean initial x0 is better? Here: ```DEFAULT OUTPUT TOTAL: -1296.67406505
Optimizer Func Output: -1318.2428505469134```. So the obtained solution is better than x0. Progress looks also very smooth to me (i used a callback to not print num-diff iterations).

Comment: interesting - did you copy paste the example? mine says `Optimizer Func Output: -1034.0922073038896`. If you watch the output iterations (in the print statement) you can see it drop from -1300ish to -1000 in the last maybe 20 iterations

Comment: (I know just reducing the tolerance in _this example_ would fix the problem, but the drop off happens much earlier with my full dataset)

Comment: Not for me. Python 3, scipy 0.19. Also i don't think much has changed for SLSQPs code (which is probably used). And yes, copy pasted last block; saw i needed the others; added in order of appearance. Again: everything smooth here, no drop. (and use a callback; num-diff func-evaluations are mostly noise, except for bug-hunting!) Using a callback (to only see feasible points in each it), i also don't think it's possible than the objective grows (monotonic line-search) (but i'm too lazy to check the maths right now).

Comment: amazing - my computer must just hate me (same version for each). Gonna test on coworkers comp

Comment: what does "(i used a callback to not print num-diff iterations)" mean? can you share any changes you made to the code? I tested on coworkers computer and it produced the same problem

Comment: It does not affect anything. Your method produces the same. See [here](https://gist.github.com/sschnug/47edb4d52dcabee9003c78849801b285). Very strange observation of yours, 32-bit or 64-bit python (not that i would expect a difference)

Comment: i'm on the 64-bit python - on macbook pro

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157493/discussion-between-rshap-and-sascha).

Answer (score 2):

As with most of my issues, it turned out to be something silly. The sum of the seed values i passed was greater than the max_budget constraint I gave it. Hence x0 was incompatible with my constraints. Why scipy didn't produce a corresponding warning or error i'm not sure. But this turned out to be the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you are getting stuck in a local minima as your function seems to be quite non-linear. Have you tried to perhaps change the optimisation method to something like BFGS.

```
res = optimize.minimize(wrapper, seed, bounds = bounds, method='BFGS',
                        tol = tol, constraints = (constraint),
                        options={'maxiter':maxiter})
```

I've tried solving the problem using this algorithm, and got -78464.52052455483.

Hope it helps

Comment: unfortunately BFGS does not support constraints and hence why the output is so high